# How to set min and max value for telerik bar chart in asp.net mvc razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2012, telerik-mvc

Is there any way to set a *maximum* and *minimum* of value on a ***"Telerik"*** bar chart in `asp.net mvc Razor`?

[image]

Comment: you have answered for grid but i had asked for bar chart
Please refer the image and answer the question

Answer (score 0):

In the ChartView you should have a Minimun parameter. I took this example from telerik.

```
 <chartView:LinearAxis  Minimum="0"
```